# Similar sounding problem but different answers due to reduced sample space

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A purse has 3 compartments. The description of the bag is as follows:

| . | Green Ball | Red Ball |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Compartment-1 | 1 | 2 |
| Compartment-2 | 2 | 3 |
| Compartment-3 | 3 | 4 |

Tom draws a single ball.

(a) Now if we ask that "what is the probability that the green ball of compartment-1 is selected" then it will lead to $\frac{1}{3}*\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{9}$.

(b) Whereas when we ask "what is the probability that the green ball comes from compartment 1" then the answer will be  $P(compartment\:1\:|\:Green)$ = $\frac{35}{122}$.

Now my doubt is that, even though these two sound the same but the answer varies because we have reduced sample space in the 2nd question, right?
In other words, in the first question, we also have to consider cases wherein a red ball may be selected, but in the 2nd question, we only consider cases where a green ball is selected and ignore red ball cases.
Is my interpretation correct? And please add more insights to it.

Comment: Consider the following question... compartment 1 has 1 green ball in it and a billion red balls.  Compartment 2 has 1 green ball and 1 red ball in it.  We randomly select a compartment and then randomly select a ball from that compartment, uniformly at random for each of these, and see that it happened to be green.  What is the probability it came from the second compartment?  Here, by the fact that we drew a green ball... we should be *very* skeptical that it came from the first compartment since that was *such* an improbable scenario, we are almost certain it came from the second instead.

Comment: Now... your answer to problem (b) is actually incorrect.  The correct answer was $\dfrac{35}{122}$, seen by Bayes' Theorem.  $\Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\Pr(B\mid A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(B)} = \dfrac{\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{7}}$

Comment: Perhaps the confusion comes from the phrasing... (b) is "*[supposing we drew a green ball] what is the probability that the green ball comes from compartment 1?*"

Comment: oh yes, that was a typo, sorry. That is actually the probability of getting a green ball i.e. denominator part.